# Using PowerShell's Add-Member results in an error

Tags: object, powershell, wmi, pipeline

Why does the script below come up with the following error?

> "Add-Member : Cannot process command because of one or more missing 
>   mandatory parameters: InputObject. 
>   +         $obj = Add-Member <<<<  -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ComputerName -Value $ComputerName 
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Add-Member], ParameterBindingException 
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingMandatoryParameter,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddMemberCommand"

#### Script

```
# Receives the computer name and stores the required results in $obj.
Function WorkerNetworkAdaptMacAddress {
    Param($ComputerName)

    $colItems = GWMI -cl "Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration" -name "root\CimV2" -comp $ComputerName -filter "IpEnabled = TRUE"
    $obj = New-Object -TypeName PSobject
    ForEach ($objItem in $colItems)
    {
        $obj = Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ComputerName -Value $ComputerName
        $obj = Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name MacAddress -Value $objItem.MacAddress
        $obj = Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IPAdress -Value $objitem.IpAddress
    }
    Write-Output $obj
}

# Receives the computer name and passes it to WorkerNetworkAdaptMacAddress.

Function Get-NetworkAdaptMacAddress {
    begin {}
    process{
        WorkerNetworkAdaptMacAddress -computername $_
    }
    end {}
}

# Passes a computer name to get-networkAdaptMacAddress
'tbh00363' | Get-NetworkAdaptMacAddress
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$objcol = @()
ForEach ($objItem in $colItems)
{
    $obj = New-Object System.Object
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ComputerName -Value $ComputerName
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name MacAddress -Value $objItem.MacAddress
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IPAdress -Value $objitem.IpAddress
    $objcol += $obj
}
Write-Output $objcol
```

Comment: what does the "@" symbol do in "$objcol = @()"

Comment: I used this script and it worked a treat.  The script seamed to fit my understanding better than the other scripts. One question, why the "$obj |" instead of "$Obj=" ?

Comment: To add membertype to object you need to pipe not to assign. read here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347695.aspx. If you consider this answer good, accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You need to move the [PSObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.psobject%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) creation into the loop. Otherwise, you'll get errors that the properties already exist on the object.

Secondly, you need to tell [`Add-Member`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849879.aspx) on which object to operate. You do it either by piping the object to the cmdlet or by specifying it on the `InputObject` parameter. Finally, return the object back to the pipeline by specifying the `PassThru` switch on the last `Add-Member` call:

```
ForEach ($objItem in $colItems)
{
    $obj = New-Object -TypeName PSobject
    Add-Member -InputObject $obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ComputerName -Value $ComputerName
    Add-Member -InputObject $obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name MacAddress -Value $objItem.MacAddress
    Add-Member -InputObject $obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IPAddress -Value $objitem.IpAddress -PassThru
}
```

Alternatively, you could simplify the process with [`New-Object's`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849885.aspx) `-Property` parameter:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName $ComputerName -Filter "IpEnabled=TRUE" | Foreach-Object {
    New-Object -TypeName PSobject -Property @{
        ComputerName=$ComputerName
        MacAddress=$_.MacAddress
        IPAddress=$_.IpAddress
    }
}
```

Or by using [`Select-Object`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849895.aspx):

```
Get-WmiObject ... | Select-Object @{n='ComputerName';e={$_.__SERVER}},MacAddress,IpAddress
```

Answer (score 4):

First you need to specify the input object to which the property should be added by *piping* it to the [Add-Member cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347695.aspx).
Then, if you want the cmdlet to return the modified object, you should invoke it with the `-PassThru` argument:

> When you use the PassThru parameter, Add-Member returns the
>   newly-extended object. Otherwise, this cmdlet does not generate any
>   output.

Here's a slightly modified version of your script:

```
$obj = $objItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ComputerName -Value $ComputerName -PassThru
```

However, since in your case you don't really need to save the output object in a new variable, you could also simply say:

```
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ComputerName -Value $ComputerName
```

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by Enrico, Shay and Christian, you should specify the object on which `Add-Member` operates, either by piping the object to `Add-Member` or by explicitly specifying the object on the `InputObject` parameter. When adding multiple members using `Add-Member` I usually add the `PassThru` switch to avoid repeating the InputObject and to provide a visual cue.

```
ForEach ($objItem in $colItems) {
  $obj = New-Object PSobject
  $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ComputerName -Value $ComputerName -PassThru ` 
       | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name MacAddress -Value $objItem.MacAddress -PassThru `
       | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IPAdress -Value $objitem.IpAddress -PassThru
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning the result of [`Add-Member`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849879.aspx) to a variable, not adding it to a property collection within `$obj`.

Instead of

```
$obj = Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ComputerName -Value $ComputerName
```

Try this:

```
Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ComputerName -Value $ComputerName -inputObject $obj
```